# Single cocoapods framework target for multiple app targets

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

workspace 'application.xcworkspace'
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'AFNetworking'

target 'Library' do
    project 'Library/Library.xcodeproj'
end 

abstract_target 'wrapper' do
    project 'project.xcodeproj'

    target "target1"
    target "target2"
    target "target3"
    target "target4"
    target "target5"
end
```

All my logic sits in `library` framework and `project` is the container for all the white label targets.

However `target1` has `Pods_wrapper_Target1.framework` linked and `target2` has `Pods_wrapper_Target2.framework` linked, etc.

But those different target frameworks are all exactly the same thing

Is there a way to configure xcode or pods to only generate a single framework output target that contains all the pods, and link that framework against all my targets?

Comment: Hi @Zayin Krige, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @MortenBjergGregersen no, unfortunately not. And my podfile is an even bigger mess now

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

workspace 'application.xcworkspace'

pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'AFNetworking'

target 'LibraryShared' do
    project 'Library Shared/LibraryShared.xcodeproj'
end

abstract_target 'WhiteLabelGroup1' do
 project 'Whitelabel1/Whitelabel1.xcodeproj'
    target "target1"
    target "target2"
end

abstract_target 'WhiteLabelGroup2' do
    project 'Whitelabel2/Whitelabel2.xcodeproj'
    target "target4"
    target "target5"
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I hoped this would be easy with CocoaPods. We have switched to Carthage now.